# Which of the following are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two examples directly from my book:

$$\{(x, y,z) : x + y + z = 1 \}$$

and

$$\{(x, y, z) : x \leq y \leq z\}$$

The book once again isn't helping me understand the concept. What are the rules I should follow to prove that these two are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: I think you're missing something in your 2nd example.  What is $y$ less than or equal to?

Comment: They aren’t, so for each of them you should try to find an axiom of vector spaces that isn’t satisfied. (I assume that in the second you want $x\le y\le z$.)

Comment: For the first: is $\langle 0,0,0\rangle$ in the set?

Comment: To be a subspace it must i) be a subset and ii) be a space via the rules for space and iii) have the same space defintions as the set on the whole. Both of those example fail scalar multiplication closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second, no, it isn't. Try taking the points
$$v=(-10,-9,-9),\;u=(-1,5,10)$$
Then we have 
$$
v-w=(-9,-14,-19)
$$
Which no longer satisfy $x\leq y \leq z$

As commented below, this space also does not satisfy scalar multiplication since 
$$-1(1,2,3)\notin V$$
$V$ your vector space

For the first, take $v=(x,y,z)$ with $x+y+z=1$. Then $-v=(-x,-y,-z)$ and 
$$-x-y-z=-(x+y+z)=-1\ne 1$$

Comment: Much simpler: $(1,2,3)$ satisfies the condition, but $-(1,2,3)$ doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check whether the sum of any two vectors which satisfy these condiions satisfies the same condition, and similarly for any scalar multiple.